# Functional in Integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have evaluated the following code:

```
k[θ_] := Sin[θ/2]^2;
Do[Print[Integrate[1/Sqrt[1 - k[θ]*(Sin^2)[ϕ]], {ϕ, 0, π/2}]], {θ, 0, π/3, π/12}]
```

But I don't know why I see

[image]

Even when I add `// N` to the expression, the problem persists in another format.

Comment: Square of Sin[x] is Sin[x]^2 not Sin^2[x].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With *Mathematica* 10.2 one gets:

```
k[θ_] = Sin[θ/2]^2;
Do[Print[Integrate[1/Sqrt[1 - k[θ]*Sin[ϕ]^2], {ϕ,0, π/2}]], {θ, 0, π/3, π/12}]
```

> ```
> π/2
>
> EllipticK[1/4 (2-(-1)^(1/12)+(-1)^(11/12))]
>
> EllipticK[1/4 (2-Sqrt[3])]
>
> EllipticK[1/4 (2-Sqrt[2])]
>
> EllipticK[1/4]
> ```

```
Do[Print[N @ Integrate[1/Sqrt[1 - k[θ]*Sin[ϕ]^2], {ϕ,0, π/2}]], {θ, 0, π/3, π/12}]
```

> ```
> 1.5708
>
> 1.57755 +2.77807*10^-17 I
>
> 1.59814
>
> 1.63359
>
> 1.68575
> ```

Comment: @Dr. Wolfgang Hintze We have the same time.

Comment: @ Willinski: yes, almost: your timestamp is 09:33:22, mine is 09:30:48, so you were late by 2 1/2 minutes ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you correct the typo in the (Sin^2)[ϕ], you get

```
k[θ_] := Sin[θ/2]^2;
Do[
  Print[Integrate[1/Sqrt[1 - k[θ]*Sin[ϕ]^2], {ϕ, 0, π/2}]], 
  {θ, 0, π/3, π/12}]
```

> ```
> π/2
>
> EllipticK[1/4 (2-(-1)^(1/12)+(-1)^(11/12))]
>
> EllipticK[1/4 (2-Sqrt[3])]
>
> EllipticK[1/4 (2-Sqrt[2])]
>
> EllipticK[1/4]
> ```